# record won't delete from database

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to delete a record using php from a database. This is supposed to happen when I click a button, no error is displayed and the query appears on the screen but the record remains on the database

phpmyadmin gives me the following code to use: DELETE FROM 'the shop'.'customer' WHERE 'customer'.'CustomerID' = 8

```
<?php
$host="localhost"; // Host name
$tbl_name="customer"; // Table name
$db_user="root";
$db_pass="";

$connect = mysql_connect("$host", "$db_user", "$db_pass");
$db_name="the_shop"; // Database name
mysql_select_db("$db_name");
if (!$connect)
 {
 die("MySQL could not connect!");
 }

if(isset($_GET['submit2'])){

$db_username = $_GET['username'];

$sql4 = "DELETE FROM 'the_shop'.'customer' WHERE 'customer'.'CustomerID' = 8"
or die('error deleting record');
mysql_query($sql4);
echo $sql4;
}
?>
```

I know this will only delete the record that has a CustomerID that = 8
my intention is that once this works I will replace CustomerID with Username and the '8' with the relevant variable that will be given a value via a form

any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Use this,It is working.
<?php
$host="localhost"; // Host name
$tbl_name="customer"; // Table name
$db_user="root";
$db_pass="";

$connect = mysql_connect("$host", "$db_user", "$db_pass");
$db_name="the_shop"; // Database name
mysql_select_db("$db_name",$connect);
if (!$connect)
{
 die("MySQL could not connect!");
  }

if(isset($_GET['submit2'])){

$db_username = $_GET['username'];

$sql4 = "DELETE FROM `the_shop`.`customer` WHERE `customer`.`CustomerID` = 8";

mysql_query($sql4,$connect) or die('error deleting record');
echo $sql4;
}
```

?>

Comment: I have no idea what you changed so it is hard for me to learn from your answer could you please let me know?

I have made the change and you are correct it is now working :)

Comment: you can check difference between 'the_shop'.'customer' and `the_shop`.`customer` ,check it in your's and rakesh's $sql4.
ie you used " ' " and you should use " ` ".

Answer (score 3):

You are using quotes instead of back tick

```
$sql4 = "DELETE FROM `the_shop`.`customer` WHERE `customer`.`CustomerID` = 8";
```

Moreover you don't need back ticks(In this case as you are not using any Reserved keywords here) as well as you are using `die()` at wrong place

Answer (score 1):

Your statement is not correct. You use quoted instead of back ticks. But you can make your statement easier.

```
$sql4 = "DELETE FROM customer WHERE CustomerID = 8";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql4 = "DELETE FROM `the_shop`.`customer` WHERE `customer`.`CustomerID` = 8"
mysql_query($sql4);or die('error deleting record');
echo $sql4;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't need to specify which database to query in your query.
   This will suffice:

   ```
   DELETE FROM customer WHERE CustomerID = 8
   ```
2. The Mysql extension is deprecated. This means that it is no longer supported by PHP and should not be used. Try [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [pdo](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.

Comment: You are using single quotes, that's invalid

Answer (score 0):

You can just use this. There is no need for you to specify the database.

```
delete from customer where CustomerID = 8
```